# How do I access a memory location directly just by using a pointer?

Tags: c

What is wrong with the following code:

```
unsigned int *ptr;    
ptr=(unsigned int*)0x1234;
*ptr=10;
/*do someting*/
*ptr=100;
```

Imp point, I have read the memory map of the microcontroller, and this location can be very much used by the programmer, so the case of not-owning-the-memory is ruled out.
All I want to find out is, can I use the above method to directly access a memory location?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: maybe you'll need to add a `volatile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is fine, unless (as you said) you are within accessible memory range.

Also I would like to add, since you mentioned microcontroller, if this is address of a SFR or a GPR then its alias (using `#define`)must already be defined in the header for the controller, so it is better you use that alias, for improved readability/understandability and portability.

**EDIT :** (As *Vlad* pointed out in the comment)
Using `volatile` will make your program more safe & reliable, as compiler will not optimize out immediate memory write, and you can be sure that the value you write is immediately written to the location you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it, but be aware of the alignment issues. Depending in your microcontroller following might happen:

```
uint16_t * p1 = (uint16_t *)0x8;
uint16_t * p2 = (uint16_t *)0x9;
*p1 = 1; // Ok
*p2 = 1; // Unaligned access -> Crash or something else
```

ARM for example requires that 16-bit variables are aligned on even addresses (divisible by 2).